# Redmine doesn't show related issues

Tags: redmine

Redmine is kind of cool, but I have searched for hours now and can't get the **related issues** to work, not even as an administrator. The dialogue is just not showing up below the parent tasks in view or edit mode of an issue.

Every user has the role manager, every user is assigned to all projects and the manager role has the permission to view and edit the issue-relations. However, they still don't show up.

Did anyone experience the same issue when setting it up? Could it be related to a plugin?

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it running! I installed the latest stable (1.3.1) again and did everything according to the install instructions found [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) and it's working now. The last time I forgot to downgrade RubyGems to 1.7.2 (from 1.8.17) which resulted in an error when installing `rubytree`. Maybe it's because this gem was missing. With this version of RubyGems, `rubytree` installs like a charm and I see the related issues :-)

But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I just run exactly into the same problem. It seems to be a conflict in redmine 1.3.x and one of the plugins I have been using for a long time. The plugin responsible for this issue was redmine_closed_issue. Deleting from vendors/plugins and then rake db:migrate_plugins got "related issues" back.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at an issue than you should see the "releated to" ..drop-down box...just add the id of the issue you wan't to make a relationship to and press "Add" button...that should do the trick. 
go through via "Issues" -> Update -> and the continue with the above.

Comment: Actually this box isn't visible, that's my problem :/

Comment: Which version of Redmine do you use? Have you freshly installed ?

Comment: Hey, I use the latest stable build 1.3.1.